# Why nltk Text.dispersion_plot() shows occurrences of words that are not in the text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm exploring the functionalities of nltk with the sample texts it has. When I make a `dispersion_plot` with the method of nltk.text.Text over text4, even if I input a list of words containing words in other languages or simply strings that are not words, the resulting plot shows as if these words had multiple occurrences in the text.

I imported some basic nltk modules and tried to explore how they worked.

```
#Importing
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
from nltk.book import *
```

But when I try to do a `dispersion_plot` which is a method (I think it is the right terminology) of the class `nltk.text.Text` I get a weird plot, showing occurrences of words that I am pretty sure are not in the text. `nltk.book` has 9 example texts, so I use for example `text4` to make the Lexical Dispersion Plot. I give it a list of words as an argument and at the end I put a words that doesn't exist like `"asfasfasaf"`. But the same following behavior would happen if my list contained words like `"bonjour"` or `"tacos"` or any other string.

```
text4.dispersion_plot(["citizens", 'democracy', "freedom", "duties", "America", "war","asfasfasaf"])
```

The result I get is:
[Lexical Dispersion Plot given by nltk.text.Text.dispersion_plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsFBU.png)

Evidently the word `"asfasfasaf"` does not occur in `text4` which is called "Inaugural Address Corpus". So, why am I getting blue ticks all over the length of the text for words like "asfasfasaf"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Do you have other code in this script, or did you (accidentally) change settings for `matplotlib`? Maybe restart your kernel, and try again just this line. The thing is: just reproduced this, and your labels are upside down. The top dispersion belongs to `"citizens"`, and your `"asfasfasaf"` string to the lowest (no dispersion). I.e., your labels are showing as: `["citizens", 'democracy', "freedom", "duties", "America", "war","asfasfasaf"][::-1]`. Hard to see how that would just happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.